# Heap allocations for bytes increase while using a direct allocation in Netty

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, netty

As per my understanding using the direct allocation API, should not allocate memory on the heap, but I still see a significant chunk of memory being used by `byte[]`

Here is how I allocate

```scala
channelContext.alloc().directBuffer()
```

**Visual VM Heap Dumps**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show where these byte[] are referenced from ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Updated the screenshot.

Comment: @NormanMaurer is the above picture clear? Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `byte[]` allocation you see here is used as internal datastructure by the `PoolChunk`. There is only once `byte[]` allocation per chunk.